# Call the window to active desktop

Tags: macos

Many applications are one-window app. When I switch to the app it does not appear on current desktop but my view is moved to the desktop where target app's window is located. I wish to change this behaviour: **on switch move target app to current desktop**. I wonder how to do?

Comment: I think that would need a 3rd party solution. There’s no native way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is option 'When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application' in Mission Control preferences. Does unticking it delivers expected behavior?

[image]

Comment: I know that option. But it does not solve my problem. Thank you for attention